# How do I use rust traits to abstract HTTP call for tests?

Tags: testing, rust

Coming from Go there are a lot of interfaces you can use to do something like the below:

```
async fn get_servers(client: &dyn std::marker::Send) -> Result<String, impl std::error::Error> {
   let servers_str = client.send().await?.text()
   let v: Value = serde_json::from_str(servers_str)?;
   
   println!("{:?}", v);
   Ok(servers_str.to_string())
   
}

// ...
get_servers(client.get(url))
```

I could pass in something that just implemented the send and return the text.  That way makes the code testable.  I thought maybe the send auto trait would do that but apparently not.  Says send not found.  Maybe some kind of impl requestbuilder?

Comment: `std::marker::Send` is just an empty trait that is used to show that a value is safe to send between threads. IIUC what you want, you will need to define your own `Client` trait.

Comment: Also note `Send` is in the prelude and you can name it without module prefixes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, this is absolutely possible and (correct me if I'm wrong) even advised. It's a programming paradigm called [*dependency injection*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

Simplified, this means in your case, pass in the dependent object via an interface (or in Rust: trait) so you can replace it at test time with an object of a different type.

Your mistake here is that the `std::marker::Send` trait does not what you think it does; it marks objects for being transferrable between threads. It's closely linked to `std::marker::Sync`, meaning, it can be accessed by multiple threads without causing race conditions.

While many libraries already have traits you can use for that purpose, in a lot of cases you will have to set up your own trait. Here, for example, we have a hello world function, that gets tested by replacing its printer with a different one, specialized for testing. We achieve that by passing the printer into the hello world function through the abstraction of a trait, as already mentioned.

```rust
trait HelloWorldPrinter {
    fn print_text(&mut self, msg: &str);
}

struct ConsolePrinter;
impl HelloWorldPrinter for ConsolePrinter {
    fn print_text(&mut self, msg: &str) {
        println!("{}", msg);
    }
}

// This is the function we want to test.
// Note that we are using a trait here so we can replace the actual
// printer with a test mock when testing.
fn print_hello_world(printer: &mut impl HelloWorldPrinter) {
    printer.print_text("Hello world!");
}

fn main() {
    let mut printer = ConsolePrinter;
    print_hello_world(&mut printer);
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    struct TestPrinter {
        messages: Vec<String>,
    }
    impl TestPrinter {
        fn new() -> Self {
            Self { messages: vec![] }
        }
    }
    impl HelloWorldPrinter for TestPrinter {
        fn print_text(&mut self, msg: &str) {
            self.messages.push(msg.to_string());
        }
    }

    #[test]
    fn prints_hello_world() {
        let mut printer = TestPrinter::new();
        print_hello_world(&mut printer);
        assert_eq!(printer.messages, ["Hello world!"]);
    }
}
```

When doing `cargo run`:

```
Hello world!
```

When doing `cargo test`:

```
     Running unittests src/main.rs

running 1 test
test tests::prints_hello_world ... ok

test result: ok. 1 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out; finished in 0.00s
```

As a little explanation, if that code doesn't explain itself:

- we create a trait `HelloWorldPrinter` whic his the only thing our `print_hello_world()` function knows about.
- we define a `ConsolePrinter` struct that we use at runtime to print the message. The `ConsolePrinter` of course has to implement `HelloWorldPrinter` to be usable with the `print_hello_world()` function.
- for testing, we write the `TestPrinter` struct that we use instead of the `ConsolePrinter`. Instead of printing, it stores what it received so we can test whether it got passed the correct message. Of course, the `ConsolePrinter` also has to implement the `HelloWorldPrinter` trait to be usable with `print_hello_world()`.

I hope that goes into the direction of your question. If you have any questions, feel free to discuss further.

I can't directly tell you what you should write to solve your problem, as your question is quite vague, but this should be the toolset you need to solve your problem. I hope.